# Is it possible to use angularjs internal 'createDateParser' in directive?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, html-input

Angular.js internally uses [`createDateInputType`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_4/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1217) to handle date and time specific input elements with ngModel binding.
In this [`createDateParser`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_4/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1167) is used to parse date/times.
for example:
definition of the [`input[date]`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_4/src/ng/directive/input.js#L214):

```
'date': createDateInputType('date', DATE_REGEXP,
    createDateParser(DATE_REGEXP, ['yyyy', 'MM', 'dd']),
    'yyyy-MM-dd'),
```

definition of the [`input[time]`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_4/src/ng/directive/input.js#L405):

```
'time': createDateInputType('time', TIME_REGEXP,
    createDateParser(TIME_REGEXP, ['HH', 'mm', 'ss', 'sss']),
   'HH:mm:ss.sss'),
```

basically it would be possible to change the used date and time formating in the source.
but there is no api/option to specify other formats. (i think that would be a good fit for ngModelOptions)

now i just want to extend on the original behavior with an directive and add a parser / formatter that uses a user specified format string. For this i need similar functionality like the `createDateParser` - so is it possible to use these internal function in a directive?

---

alternative solution would be to include moment.js as parsing/formatting library.

i have setup a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OegQYEXeBloJw5OoDLC0?p=preview) to demonstrate this - using moment.js -
but it would be better to not have to include a external lib if the functionality is somewhere in the core...
(the directive only gets active if the browser does not natively support date or time)

iam just adding a parser and a formatter at the first position with `array.unshift()` so for the formatters it will be called last. For the parser it will be called first.
The formatter just converts the angular/iso formatted string back to a date-object and formats it according the user-given `formatString`.

```
ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
    if (value) {
        var tempDate = moment(value, format_internal);
        var intDateFormatedString = tempDate.format(scope.formatString);
        return intDateFormatedString;
    }
});
```

The Parser works the same only in the other direction and with some validating.

```
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
    var resultString;
    if (viewValue) {
        // momentjs with strict parsing
        var tempDate = moment(viewValue, scope.formatString, true);
        if ( tempDate.isValid() ) {
            ctrl.$setValidity("userInput", true);
             // return as string with internal angular expected format
            resultString = tempDate.format(format_internal);
        }
    }
    return resultString;
});
```

---

only partly related:

### [How to manually rerun formatter chain in angularjs directive with ngModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368313/how-to-manually-rerun-formatter-chain-in-angularjs-directive-with-ngmodel)

hopefully the style of the 'question' is ok - 
iam not sure if i have found the right focus..
eventually it would be better to split it up somehow?